# AS3 - read unknown number of files from assets folder

Tags: actionscript-3, assets

Using ActionScript 3 I want to access multiple text files from a subfolder within my assets folder: *project/src/assets/myFiles/*

I know how to embed and read one specific text file if I know the exact file name:

```
[Embed(source="assets/myFiles/file1", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private static const FILE1:Class;

private function read():void {
  var text:String = (new FILE1() as ByteArray).toString();
}
```

Since I have multiple files in the folder *myFiles* I'd like to read all of them.
I don't know the exact number and names of these files at compile time.

Is it possible to access them by retreiving an array of objects? Or is it possible to list all the file names read them otherwise?
Since I don't know the names at compile time I don't know how to embed and access those files.

Example of my files:

- *project/src/assets/myFiles/file1*
- *project/src/assets/myFiles/file2*
- *project/src/assets/myFiles/anotherFile*

Edit: I am using **AIR**.

Edit: I am using **Flex**.

Edit: Current approach is to not use the asset directory but a dedicated (further) directory. I include this folder in the package so it and its content is automatically created in the application directory on compililation / installation. I read this folder via **FileStream** as suggested within the comments by Organis.

Comment: You cannot embed a random amount of files like that (to be more precise, you need some kind of pre-processing script that forms your assets class prior to building the application). Did you look into actually reading external files via **URLLoader** (or maybe **FileStream** if your app is AIR-based)?

Comment: @Organis Thanks a lot for your feedback! I hoped to be able to read from assets to prevent someone being able to prevent to alter those files maliciously. This is why I'd rather go without the external-file approach. But if this is the only way, I'd do so. Pre-processing my code seems to be a legit approach, but seems to be some kind of overkill to me.

Comment: Weeeell... you may go with a zipped folder as the only file to embed. However, I think it's better to work out how to encrypt/verify/validate your data (if you think about it, they could probably be altered inside your SWF as well) rather then embed everything and trust the data.

Comment: @Basti - are you using AIR?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Yes, I am using AIR.

Comment: For performance reasons, you probably don't want to embed a whole ton of assets.  Since you're using AIR you can parse a directory and load all files from it Asynchronously - that is likely going to be your best bet.  If there is a file integrity issue, you could sign each file (run a script that creates an MD5 hash based off each files bytes, then when you load a file in your app check if file still has the same signature.   Keep in mind a clever person can probably decompile your app and figure out the signature technique you use.

Comment: If you don't have that many assets (or they are all text files which seems to be the case?) then the pre-compile script makes the most sense.  What IDE are you using?  Most of the code IDE's have an way to automate a script running when you build/compile.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I'm using FlashBuilder 4.7. Our build machine uses gradle. Current approach is to not use the asset directory but a dedicated other directory. I include this in the package so it is automatically created in the application directory on compililation / installation.